# Function difference from Solidity 4.4 to newer versions

Tags: solidity

I'm returning to programming today on Solidity (I was used to 4.4), and I'm now facing an issue that I don't know how to fix with the below topic:

```
 //name this contract whatever you’d like
contract ERC20Token is StandardToken {
function () {
 //if ether is sent to this address, send it back.
 throw;
 }
```

It works fine on Solidity 4.4, but when I try to do so on any newer version, I got the following error: ParserError: Expected a state variable declaration. If you intended this as a fallback function or a function to handle plain ether transactions, use the "fallback" keyword or the "receive" keyword instead. function () { ^

Done someone know how to mitigate that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to remove it.

**More background**

It's changed more than once.

That syntax dates back to a time when the default, undeclared fallback function was payable and could receive funds. That function looks like a guard to make sure it doesn't happen. That default behavior was removed so there should be no need to block it.

The newer versions have gone through revisions, so the following depends on "how new?"

The unnamed function was used as a "fallback" in the past. Then, the `payable` keyword was added. Your function doesn't have `payable`, so transactions would be blocked before they get to `throw`.

Later, the unnamed function syntax (`function ()`) was split into `fallback ()` and `receive()`.

A modern compiler (not 100% sure about the timing/version but you can confirm in release notes) would not accept funds by default so there is no need to declare anything to block the behavior you don't want.

Hope it helps.